# How do I have a random int from 1 to 6 using math.random() in java?

Tags: java, random, int

I'm writing a method in java which relates to a die throw and I try to use the math.random() but i realized that 0 is included in the random integers involved. Additionally, I don't quite get the *7 part what does it mean?

I went to research from the Java API but it doesn't mention any bit about this or is it I am doing the wrong research? Thanks so much for reading!

```
public int dieThrow()
{
    int num = (int)(Math.random() *7); //returns an integer 
    return num;
}
```

Comment: What does `Math.random()` _do_ exactly?

Comment: This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it randomly chooses an int.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Go read the API.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty simple exercise. You observe that 0 is a possible outcome, so you simply + 1 to the result, like so:

```
public int throwDie()
{
    return (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```